# How to publish rtmp stream in Wowza?

Tags: video-streaming, wowza

I want to publish one rtmp stream from rtmp://someothersite.com/live/ and deliver the m3u8 stream to ios and android device.

I decide to use Wowza and have done some settings following by this article http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?36

There is:

```
Publishing the stream (RTMP based encoder)

Enter the Server URL and Stream Name information below and click the Publish or Start button on the encoder:

Server URL: rtmp://[wowza-address]/live
Stream Name: myStream
```

I want to know where need I input the server url and name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can do it with two way . 
I understand that you wanna get a stream from anywhere else , and want to stream it over your wowza server , or wanna save the X stream and start re-streaming it over wowza .

First way , you can get the live stream via ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://remoteXstreamFromAnyWhereElse/playlist/first -f flv
```

rtmp://yourWowzaIp:1935/live/now .

From now on you take the stream with ffmpeg and re stream it to wowza . And
in live example you can reach your "now" stream well.

The other is again with ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://remoteZstream/StreamsName/fileName -vcodec copy -acodec copy
```

-f new.avi

and the other cmd command is like that

```
ffmpeg -i video="new.avi" -r 30 -b:v 128k -f flv rtmp://wowzaIp/live/now2
```

The other way is [and the best way for me ]

Edit the xml StartupStream in 
C:\Program Files\Wowza Media Systems\Wowza Media Server 3.1.2\conf

Add the following line to the

```
<StartupStreams><StartupStream><Application>live/_definst_</Application<MediaCasterType>rtp</MediaCasterType><StreamName>rtsp://yourRemoteZReStreamingProviderServer/App/File<StreamName> </StartupStream>
```

Then restart the wowza server . You can see that in console 
the stream starts . The fastest way is to re stream that anystream . For further more information find rlanham in wowza .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download an RTMP encoder. Try this one:
http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html